# Why is $\frac{d}{dt} \langle \psi | = (\frac{d}{dt} | \psi \rangle )^{\dagger} $?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, hilbert-space, differentiation

When we want to find the equation of motion of the density matrix, we use the property :

$$\frac{d}{dt} \langle \psi | = \left(\frac{d}{dt} | \psi \rangle \right)^{\dagger} $$

Said differently, the time derivative and the hermitian conjugate "commute".

We use it in the proof about equation of motion for the density matrix :

$$ \frac{d}{dt} (| \psi \rangle \langle \psi |) = \frac{H}{ih} | \psi \rangle \langle \psi | - | \psi \rangle \langle \psi | \frac{H}{ih}$$

But I don't understand why it is true from math point of view.

I see "intuitively" why it is true when I have a column vector that I transpose, to make the derivative before or after the transposition won't change the result.

But is there a more formal proof using some properties on Hermitian scalar product ? I am looking for such a thing.

Comment: To assemble such a proof, you might start by producing an eigenbasis of the time derivative operator.

Answer (score 16):

Formally we have 
$$ \left( \frac{d}{dt}| \psi(t) \rangle\right)^{\dagger}
~=~\left(\lim_{t^{\prime} \to t} \frac{ | \psi(t^{\prime}) \rangle - | \psi(t) \rangle}{t^{\prime}-t}\right)^{\dagger} 
~=~\lim_{t^{\prime} \to t} \frac{ | \psi(t^{\prime}) \rangle^{\dagger} - | \psi(t) \rangle ^{\dagger}}{t^{\prime}-t}$$
$$~=~\lim_{t^{\prime} \to t} \frac{ \langle \psi(t^{\prime}) | - \langle  \psi(t) |}{t^{\prime}-t} ~=~\frac{d}{dt}\langle \psi(t) |. $$

Comment: Nice, do we need any conditions on the second equality (existence of the derivative?) or does conjugation always commute with limiting?

Comment: Conjugation $\dagger :{\cal H}\to {\cal H}^{\ast}\cong {\cal H}$ is an anti-linear isometry between Hilbert spaces, and hence continuous, so that it commutes with limiting.

Comment: But $\mathcal{H}\cong\mathcal{H}^*$ only holds in the finite dimensional case or the bounded infinite dimensional case; are those requirements necessary?

Answer (score 3):

The bra-ket notation can muddy the issue somewhat.  You want to know why, for some $\psi$,

$$\frac{d}{dt} \psi^\dagger = \big(\frac{d}{dt}\psi\big)^\dagger$$

Note that

$$\frac{d}{dt}\psi^\dagger := \lim_{\Delta t\rightarrow 0} \frac{\psi^\dagger(t+\Delta t) - \psi^\dagger(t)}{\Delta t}$$

But of course, since $\Delta t$ is a real number,

$$ \frac{\psi^\dagger(t+\Delta t) - \psi^\dagger(t)}{\Delta t} = \left(\frac{\psi(t+\Delta t) - \psi(t)}{\Delta t}\right)^\dagger $$

(ignoring subtleties like domain compatibility and such which is generally ignored in most physics contexts).

---

To address the comments by OP:

Let
$$ \lim_{\Delta t\rightarrow 0} \frac{A(t+\Delta t)-A(t)}{\Delta t} = A'(t)$$

This means that for all $\epsilon >0$, there exists some $\delta>0$ such that
$$ |\Delta t|<\delta \implies \big\Vert\frac{A(t+\Delta t)-A(t)}{\Delta t} - A'(t) \big\Vert < \epsilon$$

where $\Vert \cdot \Vert$ is the operator norm.  However, the operator norm of an operator $O$ is equal to the operator norm of $O^\dagger$, and since the adjoint operation distributes over addition and multiplication by real numbers, it immediately follows that

$$ |\Delta t|<\delta \implies \big\Vert\frac{A^\dagger(t+\Delta t)-A^\dagger(t)}{\Delta t} - [A'(t)]^\dagger \big\Vert < \epsilon$$

which is another way of saying that

$$ \frac{d}{dt}A^\dagger \equiv \lim_{\Delta t\rightarrow 0} \frac{A^\dagger(t+\Delta t)-A^\dagger(t)}{\Delta t} = [A'(t)]^\dagger \equiv \left[\frac{d}{dt}A\right]^\dagger$$

Comment: I tried to do this but here you use the fact you can intervet the limit and the dagger. How do we know we can do this ?

Comment: That's a reasonable question, and the answer depends on how deeply you want to go.  The operator norm of some operator $A$ is equal to the operator norm of $A^\dagger$  - you can use this fact to demonstrate that if you have a sequence of operators $\{a_n\}$ which converges to $A$, then the sequence $\{a_n^\dagger\}$ converges to $A^\dagger$, and take the limit that way.

Comment: @StarBucK I've added to my answer to justify the exchange of the limit and the adjoint operation.

Answer (score 3):

Let's see if this argument is good enough. Pick a basis of time-independent states $\left\{|\psi_i\rangle\right\}$. I think you can at least allow me to write
\begin{equation}
\left[ \frac{d}{dt} \left( \langle  \phi| \psi_i \rangle \right)\right]^* = \frac{d}{dt}  \left( \langle  \phi| \psi_i \rangle^* \right)  \, ,
\end{equation}
being this just the derivative of a $\mathbb{C}$ number.

With that given, we have
\begin{eqnarray}
  \left[ \left(\frac{d}{dt}\langle  \phi| \right) | \psi_i \rangle \right]^* &=& \left[ \frac{d}{dt} \left( \langle  \phi| \psi_i \rangle \right)\right]^* = \frac{d}{dt}  \left( \langle  \phi| \psi_i \rangle^* \right) = \frac{d}{dt}  \left( \langle \psi_i | \phi \rangle \right) 
\\
&=& \langle \psi_i |\left( \frac{d}{dt}  | \phi \rangle \right) = \left[ \left(  \frac{d}{dt}  | \phi \rangle \right)^{\dagger} | \psi_i \rangle\right]^*  \, ,
\end{eqnarray} 
where in the last step we just used the definition of adjoint. This being valid for all $|\psi_i \rangle$, we can conclude we have found the adjoint we were looking for.